# How do I sort out this "NameError"?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.3, nameerror

```
def Get_Details():
    Student_Name = input("Enter the name of the student: ")
    Coursework_Mark = int(input("Enter the coursework mark achieved by the student: "))
    while Coursework_Mark < 0 or Coursework_Mark >60:
        print("Try again, remember the coursework mark is out of 60.")
        Coursework_Mark = int(input("Enter the coursework mark achieved by the student: "))

    Prelim_Mark = int(input("Enter the prelim mark achieved by the student: "))
    while Prelim_Mark < 0 or Prelim_Mark > 90:
        print("Try again, remember the prelim mark is out of 90.")
        Prelim_Mark = int(input("Enter the prelim mark achieved by the student: "))

    return Student_Name, Coursework_Mark, Prelim_Mark

def Calculate_Percentage(Coursework_Mark, Prelim_Mark):

    Percentage = ((Coursework_Mark + Prelim_Mark)/150) * 100

    if Percentage >= 70:
        Grade = "A"
    elif 60 >= Percentage <= 69:
        Grade = "B"
    elif 50 >= Percentage <= 59:
        Grade = "C"
    elif 45 >= Percentage <= 50:
        Grade = "D"
    else:
        Grade = "No Award"

    return Percentage, Grade


def Display_Results(Student_Name, Grade):
    print(Student_Name + " achieved a grade " + str(Grade) + ".")

#MAIN PROGRAM
Student_Name, Coursework_Mark, Prelim_Mark = Get_Details()
Percentage = Calculate_Percentage(Coursework_Mark, Prelim_Mark)
Display_Results(Student_Name, Grade)
```

At the end of the program I receieve:

```
Program.py", line 41, in <module>
    Display_Results(Student_Name, Grade)
NameError: name 'Grade' is not defined
```

How can this be fixed? Please help, thank you.

***This program asks the user their name, coursework mark (out of 60) and prelim mark (out of 90) and calculates their percentage which is send to their screen as a grade along with their name.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `Calculate_Percentage` returns two values, Percentage and Grade. It looks like you wanted to assign them to a separate variable each exactly like you did with three values from the Get_Details call in the line above.

So last two lines should look like this:

```
Percentage, Grade = Calculate_Percentage(Coursework_Mark, Prelim_Mark)
Display_Results(Student_Name, Grade)
```

Please use a Pythonic naming convention to make your code more readable. For example variable names are usually all_lower_case.